# Number of commits reduced after rebasing feature branch over master

Tags: git, version-control

So I have forked a branch from `master`, lets say `feature`. Both branches got differing commits added to them afterwards. As of now,  `feature` currently has 1537 commits, and `master` has 1515 commits.

In order to get some updates, I rebased the `feature` over `master`, so after doing `git rebase -i master` on `feature`, the number of commits are reduced to 1532 (`feature` branch).

I can't think of a situation where this is possible. Say at the time of fork, both had `x` commits, and later, `y` commits were added to `master`, whereas `z` commits were added to `feature`. So `master` has `x+y` commits and `feature` has `x+z` commits.
If `feature` has been rebased over master, then it should have `x+y+z` commits, and at least not less than `x+z`. What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rebase works something like this:

```
foreach (commit) {
    calculate diff
    apply diff
    git add
    git commit
}
```

If there's any duplication between your work on `feature` and `master`, then it's likely that many of these reduce to empty commits.  Thus Git elided them.

If you invoke `rebase` with the `--keep-empty` flag, these empty commits should be preserved.

Comment: Oh, so git can recognize similar commits in the history and remove the later ones?

Comment: @goelakash - It's not that it recognises identical commits.  Instead, a rebase involves taking each commit from `feature` one-by-one, then replaying it on top of `master` and committing the result.  Sometimes that would result in an empty commit, which Git ignores by default.

Comment: Okay, I understand now. Thanks a lot! :D